# Filter python dictionary with dictionary-comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary that is really a geojson:

```
points = {
    'crs': {'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'}, 'type': 'name'},
    'features': [
        {'geometry': {
            'coordinates':[[[-3.693162104185235, 40.40734504903418],
                            [-3.69320229317164, 40.40719570724241],
                            [-3.693227952841606, 40.40698546120488],
                            [-3.693677594635894, 40.40712700492216]]],
            'type': 'Polygon'},
         'properties': {
             'name': 'place1',
             'temp': 28},
         'type': 'Feature'
        },
        {'geometry': {
            'coordinates': [[[-3.703886381691941, 40.405197271972035],
                             [-3.702972834622821, 40.40506272989243],
                             [-3.702552994966045, 40.40506798079752],
                             [-3.700985024825222, 40.405500820623814]]],
            'type': 'Polygon'},
         'properties': {
             'name': 'place2',
             'temp': 27},
         'type': 'Feature'
        },
        {'geometry': {
            'coordinates': [[[-3.703886381691941, 40.405197271972035],
                             [-3.702972834622821, 40.40506272989243],
                             [-3.702552994966045, 40.40506798079752],
                             [-3.700985024825222, 40.405500820623814]]],
            'type': 'Polygon'},
         'properties': {
             'name': 'place',
             'temp': 25},
         'type': 'Feature'
        }
    ],
    'type': u'FeatureCollection'
}
```

I would like to filter it to stay only with places that have a specific temperature, for example, more than 25 degrees Celsius.

I have managed to do it this way:

```
dict(crs = points["crs"],
     features = [i for i in points["features"] if i["properties"]["temp"] > 25],
     type = points["type"])
```

But I wondered if there was any way to do it more directly, with dictionary comprehension.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The only more direct way would be to use a literal. Why would you need a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: your current approach is not so bad at all

Comment: Looking at your data structure, I think the only thing that's changing is the list of features - so what you've got already, using a list comprehension, looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: Haven't you considered using http://geopandas.org/ and do the filter with it?

Comment: Thank you very much to all. The reason for my question is because I have a function in which I perform this filter many times over a much larger dictionary, and I wanted to know if there was any more efficient way of filtering it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late. A dict compreheneison won't help you since you have only three keys. But if you meet the following conditions: 1. you don't need a copy of `features` (e.g. your dict is read only); 2. you don't need index access to `features`, you my use a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension:

```
dict(crs = points["crs"],
                features = (i for i in points["features"] if i["properties"]["temp"] > 25),
                type = points["type"])
```

The generator is created in constant time, while the list comprehension is created in O(n). Furthermore, if you create a lot of those dicts, you have only one copy of the `features` in memory.